# Can MassTransit consumers be triggered by the message contract class name

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

We are wanting to use MassTransit with Azure Service Bus across different Azure web apps. To keep with an existing pattern, we want to define consumers and the messages they respond to by the message type. If two message types have the same members, it seems all the consumers that are registered with a type with the same members is triggered.

eg `Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderCancelled> context)` and `Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderCreated> context)` where the classes are both:

```
  public record OrderCancelled(int OrderId, DateTime Date)
```

and

```
  public record OrderCreated(int OrderId, DateTime Date)
```

I have done something along these lines, and when one of those messages is published on the Azure Service Bus topic that these consumers subscribe to, both of the consumers are called.
I've noticed that MassTransit adds a custom field to the message:

```
MT-MessageType: urn:message:Business.Messages.Events:OrderCancelled
```

So it does have some way of knowing which type was used to send the message, even if the `context.Message` is deserialized JSON. (This MT-MessageType is available in `context.ReceiveContext.TransportHeaders`).

Is there a configuration to ensure just the intended consumer responds to a message of the given type?

Thanks, Paul

Comment: Are you using the default JSON format with message envelope, or are you using RAW JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MassTransit will only deliver messages to consumers that match the message type (including both the namespace and message type name).

The *only* exception to this rule is when using the RAW JSON message deserializer with the **default** options. Originally, the RAW JSON message deserializer was built to support consuming messages from external (non-MassTransit) applications that don't specify a message type. Which means the default options for the RAW JSON deserializer will dispatch the message to all consumers, as no message type check is performed.

To use RAW JSON between MassTransit applications, additional options must be specified:

`cfg.UseRawJsonSerializer(RawSerializerOptions.AddTransportHeaders | RawSerializerOptions.CopyHeaders);`

This is straight [out of the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/serialization#options).

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's great. We're using `cfg.UseRawJsonSerializer()`. (For what it's worth, I was looking through the docs as thoroughly as possible).

Comment: So, good guess on my part? Hope this helps you sort it out.

Comment: Yes, seems like an informed guess! I did a quick test and it worked well. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, in case it's useful for anyone, publishing messages from Azure Service Bus Explorer allows you to add headers. Adding `MT-MessageType` ensured the message was delivered to the correct consumer.